# A variable('person') is not defined ? (basic map method, React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render the information contained in an object. So I use the map method like this,

```
<ul> 
    {persons.map(person => <li key={person.id}> person.name </li>)}
</ul>
```

In VS code and console on the browser, there were no error. But in the main screen it display 'person' is not defined. As far as I know, I am executing the map method correctly. How can I fix this ? Here are the rest of the code. How can

App.js

```
    import { useState } from 'react'
    
    
    const App = () => {
      const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
        { 
          name: 'Arto Hellas',
          id: 1 
        }
      ])
    
      const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')
    
      const addName = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
    
        const nameObject = {
          name: newName,
          id: persons.length + 1
        }
    
        setPersons(persons.concat(nameObject))
        setNewName('')
      }
      console.log(persons)
    
      const handleNameChange = (event) => {
        setNewName(event.target.value)
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h2> Phonebook </h2>
    
          <form onSubmit={addName}>
            <div>
              name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleNameChange} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <button type="submit"> add </button>
            </div>
          </form>
    
          <h2> Numbers </h2>
    
          <ul> 
            {persons.map(person => <li key={person.id}> person.name </li>)}
          </ul>
          
    
        </div>
      )
    }

export default App
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mistake with using persone inside `<li/>`

```
<li> key={person.id}> {person.name} </li>
```

And its works. I didint see 'A variable('person') is not defined' in errors

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-thompson-7f6hqj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Was a silly mistake and you're right. I forget to put the curly braces, {} inside the person.name. Other thing is that I ran my application twice on two different ports. The one that got an error was coded differently and hence the error occur. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `person.name` to `{person.name}`

Answer (score 3):

You're missing on minor code details.

```
<ul>
  {persons.map((person) => {
    return <li key={person.id}> {person.name} </li>;
  })}
</ul>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember to put inside a JSX element the variables of the component between "{}".